# How to define what survey responses represent in R?

Tags: r, survey, survival-analysis

How can you define the responses for survey items in R?

For instance, this is SPSS data imported, but it strips the  definitions when you translate them.

`data$q27` prints the definitions, but
`as.numeric(data$q27)` prunes them

How can I redefine them?

[image: survey strip]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the attributes directly, you can do:

```
attr(data$q27, "value.labels") <- c("No" = 2, "Yes" = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, it seems to be a factor problem. 
In my example below, answers are codify 2 for yes and 1 for No

```
answer <-c("Yes", "No", "Yes") 
data=data.frame(answer) 
as.numeric(data$answer)
```

Lets say I want 1 for Yes and 0 for No, I just need to convert the column back to character and factor with the labels I desire:

```
data$answer <- factor(as.character(data$answer), levels=c("Yes","No"), labels = c(1, 0))
```

I hope this helps you!